# How to send data via Swagger when field is set as Optional

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a springboot application. My endpoint/controller is expecting a requestbody. The object that gets constructed from the request body contains an Optional field. When I go on swagger, it autogenerates the structure of the request body. As an example:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "age": "string",
  "address": "string",
  "alive": {
    "empty": true,
    "present": true
  }
}
```

So essentially in my object, the alive field is set as an Optional;

`private Optional<String> alive;`

My question is how can i set a value to `alive` when sending a request via swagger?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Docket` to the part you created in your `Swagger` configuration as follows.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            // add this 
            .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class);
}
```